# How to float an aside on a different part of the page for a media query

Tags: css, media-queries

Picture the following:

A navbar on top, a sidebar on each side of the page (left and right) and a content div sandwiched between those asides. Everything looks great on a desktop.

Enter a media query for a single column layout for mobile view. Now the layout is Nav, left sidebar underneath, content under that and the right sidebar under the content.

My question is how to get the right sidebar under the left sidebar for the mobile media query but leave it untouched for the desktop view, without touching the markup and only changing the CSS. Here is a link to a fiddle to show what I mean:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eEpaY/)

Everything for the desktop layout is inside of a

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { }
```

CSS block.

Comment: By changing the markup, it would be easy. Can you use a javascript solution?

Comment: Yep JavaScript is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've asked for "*only changing the CSS*". So first of all maybe there is a solution with the new css [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) functionality. But then why not using a much simpler way with changing the markup only a little bit ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eEpaY/2/)).

In the following example I've removed every piece of code not needed to demonstrate the solution in your fiddle.

You could just move the right sidebar before the content element and then float them left/right in desktop mode.

```
.sidebar {
    width: 20%;
}

.content {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}

.sidebar_right {
    float: right;
}

.sidebar_left {
    float: left;
}
```

In mobile mode, you remove the float so that the 3 elements get back to their original "markup position".

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {    
    .sidebar, .content {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```